# Calculate distance between two coordinates along lines

Tags: point, distance, line, network, gvsig

I have a map with two layers: a map of the streets of Montevideo, and a map of shops with the lat long location. I would like to calculate the distance between each shop and the nearest one, along the streets (not a line between the locations).

Is there any tool that could help me with this? I am using gvSIG.

Comment: Search here for manhattan distance. Here's [one question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110431/how-do-i-calculate-manhattan-distance-with-postgis) with an answer using PostgreSQL which may give some hints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the network analysis extension compatible with gvSIG 1.12. It can be installed from the gvSIG add-ons manager (menu Tools > Add-ons manager, select the “Installation from URL” option, and the “org.gvsig.graph (1.1.0-1241 version)” plugin)